# Pass C# simple struct Jagged Array (array of arrays) to C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport, jagged-arrays

I have a third-party C++ DLL, that came with its header file as API.
I want to be able to call one of its functions.
The C++ header file looks like this:

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __WATCOMC__
#define EXPORT extern int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
#define IMPORT extern int __declspec(dllimport) __stdcall
#endif

#ifdef _WINDOWS
#ifndef EXPORT
#define EXPORT extern int
#endif
#endif

#ifndef EXPORT
#define EXPORT int
#endif

#ifndef EXIMPORT
#define EXIMPORT EXPORT
#endif
.
.
.
.
typedef struct
  { double x;
    double y;
  } coordpt;

.
.
.
.
EXIMPORT CPlusPlusFunction(coordpt **arrayOfArrays,int NumberOfArrays,int *arrayContainesTheSizeOfEachArray....);
.
.
.
```

C# code:

The struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public class coordpt
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public double x;
        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public double y;

        public coordpt(double x, double y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

The DLL import:

```
[DllImport(@"PathToDLL", EntryPoint =
         "CPlusPlusFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int CPlusPlusFunction( IntPtr[] arrayOfArrays,int NumberOfArrays,int[] arrayContainesTheSizeOfEachArray....);
```

Marshaling the ArrayOfArrays for sending as a pointer array:

```
... 
IntPtr[] ptrArr = marshel2Dto1Ptr(ArrayOfArrays );
int result = textile_nesting_api(ptrArr , NumberOfArrays, arrayContainesTheSizeOfEachArray...);
```

The marshaling function:

```
public static IntPtr[] marshel2Dto1Ptr(coordpt[][] inputArrayOfArrays)
        {
            IntPtr[] pointerArray = new IntPtr[inputArrayOfArrays.GetLength(0)];
            for (var i = 0; i < inputArrayOfArrays.Length; i++)
            {
                int sizeOfCoordpt = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(coordpt));
                IntPtr inputArrayJaggedRowPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeOfCoordpt * inputArrayOfArrays[i].Length);
                int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(coordpt));
                for (int j = 0; j < inputArrayOfArrays[i].Length; j++)
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(inputArrayOfArrays[i][j], inputArrayJaggedRowPtr + j * structSize, true);
                pointerArray[i] = inputArrayJaggedRowPtr;
            }
            return pointerArray;
        }
```

The questions are:

1. Have I done something wrong? I'm getting this error:
   `System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'` and I'm not sure this is the reason.
2. Is there an easier way for sending an array of arrays of the coordpt struct when the DLL wants to get it as  `CPlusPlusFunction(..coordpt **arrayOfArrays ..)`

Comment: If you can find a copy of Adam Nathan's `P/Invoke` book (https://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X), the answer is probably in there

Comment: The coordpt declaration is not correct, the 2nd field offset must be [FieldOffset(8)] since the x field needs 8 bytes of storage.  And should be a struct, not a class.  Best to not use LayoutKind.Explicit at all.

Comment: `i < inputArrayOfArrays.Length` should be `i < inputArrayOfArrays.GetLength(0)`